# Can't understand how to get rid of goto

Tags: c++

This question probably is kind of silly, but I really need help.

I'm pretty new in programming and as far as I know, `goto` is a thing that I should avoid in my code. And a couple of days ago I wrote this for my school task:

```
bool create_way(int start_index) {
if (start_index == members.get_size() - 1) {
    flowToDrain.push_back(start_index);
    return true;
}

find_any_way:
int max_index = INT_MIN;
int max_bandwidth = INT_MIN;

for (int i = 0; i < network[start_index].routes.get_size(); i++) {

    int index = network[start_index].routes.find(i);
    int bandwidth = network[index].bandwidth.find(start_index);

    if (bandwidth > max_bandwidth && !network[index].visited) {
        max_index = index;
        max_bandwidth = bandwidth;
    }
}

network[start_index].visited = true;

if (max_index != INT_MIN) {
    if (!create_way(max_index)) goto find_any_way;
    else {
        flowToDrain.push_back(start_index);
        return true;
    }
}
else return false; }
```

I wrote `goto` to keep in mind the logic of the algorithm, but now I'm really stuck with it. And since then I haven't came up with any idea how to get rid of this. I understand, that it should be a loop, probably with `continue`, but I can't understand what expression to check in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, though you should test it:

```
while(1) {
    int max_index = INT_MIN;
    int max_bandwidth = INT_MIN;

    for (int i = 0; i < network[start_index].routes.get_size(); i++) {

        int index = network[start_index].routes.find(i);
        int bandwidth = network[index].bandwidth.find(start_index);

        if (bandwidth > max_bandwidth && !network[index].visited) {
            max_index = index;
            max_bandwidth = bandwidth;
        }
    }

    network[start_index].visited = true;

    if (max_index != INT_MIN) {
        if (!create_way(max_index)) continue;
        else {
            flowToDrain.push_back(start_index);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, it works. So, you have an infinite loop, but when there is an else-case, it doesn't matter because function will return false? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @kolojeropey your `goto` was an infinite loop as well, because it just went back no matter what. and since all other paths in `if-then-else` return from the function, breaking the loop, it was safe to assume it will eventually end.